# how change some words translation in wagtail admin?

Tags: django, locale, wagtail

i integrate Wagtail into my Django project and my language is persian ( fa )

i use multilang in django project and wagtail admin panel words translation to persian works and is perfect

but in wagtail admin panel some words not translated and i want to add this words

i found this words in `wagtail/admin/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` (en) but in `wagtail/admin/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` (fa) does not exists

how can i use my custom locale file for wagtail admin panel? how can i fix this?

[image: example]